# ServiceStack Ormlite: System.InvalidProgramException JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation

Tags: c#, servicestack, .net-4.5, ormlite-servicestack

Hi i'm running ServiceStack with Ormlite and I encountered this error. Previously it is working fine. I'm not sure what I have changed that caused this error. I just used a simple db.Select() call and it throws this error. I tried various ways, like updating the nuget packages, clean and rebuild the project, etc and none of them works.

```
System.InvalidProgramException was caught
  _HResult=-2146233030
  _message=JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation.
  HResult=-2146233030
  IsTransient=false
  Message=JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation.
  Source=ServiceStack.OrmLite
  StackTrace:
       at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteConfig.get_ExecFilter()
       at ServiceStack.OrmLite.ReadConnectionExtensions.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter)
       at ServiceStack.OrmLite.ReadConnectionExtensions.Select[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Expression`1 predicate)
   InnerException:
```

can anyone suggest what might went wrong?

Comment: This usually means that the program is corrupt. Are all your `ServiceStack` assemblies intact? might one of them got corrupted? Maybe try re-downloading them and referencing them again.

Comment: I just done a simple ServiceStack app from scratch and it gave me the same error! something is messed up, but i don't know what is it. hmm..

Comment: Maybe the method to be jitted was dynamically generated and too big or hit some other limit.

Answer (score 19):

I turned off IntelliTrace and it works again.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Comment: Were you using 'Events Only' or 'Events and call information'?

Comment: You can add "*ServiceStack.*" in Modules exception list from IntelliTrace settings. That way you'll still be able to have both events and call information for you libraries.

Comment: For me the same. I had this Exception raised in my WCF project. Debugging the WCF source code revealed that this InvalidProgramException occured on this line  MethodInfo opMethod = opDesc.OperationMethod; where opDesc is an instance of System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription.

It only occured with 'Event and Call Information', not 'Events Only'.